# Same scales in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to both scales equals range, how to do this in ggplot2:

ggplot2 reproducible example

> `mtcars %>%     ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = drat)) +    geom_point()`

Comment: try `ylim` and `xlim`

Comment: without force  with ylim and xlim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(wrapr)

mtcars %.>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = wt, y = drat)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(
    xlim = c(min(pmin(.$wt, .$drat)), max(pmax(.$wt, .$drat))) -> sc_range,
    ylim = sc_range
  )
```